# Render pilet under a tab

Tags: micro-frontend, piral

I want to render a pilet under a tab. I have managed to render the pilet name as a tab but content can't be renderd. I am using  Fluent UI Pivots.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/pivot
The idea is when you click a a Tab/Pivot name the micro front end should be loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I see is to use a conventional extension slot for doing that. A more obvious way (for pilet developers) would be to have a custom API like `registerTab` for registering tab components.

Following the easy way you could the following for your `Pivot`:

```js
export const MyTabComponent = () => {
  return (
    <ExtensionSlot name="tabs" render={children => (
      <Pivot>
        {children.map((child, i) =>
          <PivotItem headerText="First Tab" key={i}>
            {child}
          </PivotItem>
        )}
      </Pivot>
    )} />
  );
};
```

Using this in your app shell all you'd need to do in a pilet is register an extension for `tabs`.

```js
export function setup(api) {
  api.registerExtension("tabs", () => <div>Sample content!</div>);
}
```